# Running pig scripts giving me the error: You are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser (which is "hdfs")

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hue

I'm using cloudera quickstart vm-4.7.
I'm unable to run pig scripts as it's throwing the following error message :

> Cannot access: /pigwordcount/wordcountinput.txt. Note: You are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser (which is "hdfs").
>
> [Errno 2] File /pigwordcount/wordcountinput.txt not found

It is giving me "file not found" but already the files were present in the directory user/cloudera/pigwordcount

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: In your Pig script, you should probably put the full path to wordcountinput.txt, e.g. /user/cloudera/wordcountinput.txt

Comment: Thanks Romain. it worked.. now after providing the full path.

Comment: actually im using CDH4.7, quickstart vm, so i had this hue version only, can i know how to update this hue in CDH4.7 quickstart vm..?

Comment: You could try to upgrade the cluster in CM but most probably downloading a VM with 5.4 might be simpler